# How to convert list of Json string to JsonObject using Gson

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have a list of Json string: `List<String> jsonStringList`, I want to convert it to a single JsonObject using Gson, may I know what is the best way to do it?

I know I can parse them one by one like:

```
for (String jsonString : jsonStringList) {
    JsonElement parsed = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
}
```

But how do I join them together? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String s1 = "{\n" +
                "    \"userName\": \"RandomDiscord Name\",\n" +
                "    \"permissions\": \"read\"\n" +
                "  }";
        String s2 = "{\n" +
                "    \"userName\": \"RandomDiscord Name1\",\n" +
                "    \"permissions\": \"read2\"\n" +
                "  }";
        List<String> jsonStringList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{s1, s2});
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        for (String jsonString : jsonStringList) {
            JsonElement obj = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
            arr.add(obj);
        }
        String jsonString = arr.toString();
        System.out.println(jsonString);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("CustomObject", arr);
        } catch(JSONParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

Try to use **`JSONArray`** and while iterating List just add that object into JsonArray.

### For above code, i am getting below output
O/P

```
[{"userName":"RandomDiscord Name","permissions":"read"},{"userName":"RandomDiscord Name1","permissions":"read2"}]
{"CustomObject":[{"userName":"RandomDiscord Name","permissions":"read"},{"userName":"RandomDiscord Name1","permissions":"read2"}]}
```

Comment: Hi I want to convert it to `gson.JsonObject`, I tried your code with `JsonArray` then I do `jsonArray.getAsJsonObject()` but throw an Exception: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Response did not contain a JSON Object` may I know how can I fix it?